# Use high API function when targeting lower API

Tags: android, api

in my app minSdkVersion="16" and targetSdkVersion="19". And I wish to use MediaMuxer that introduced in API 18. So when I detetect the API on the phone how can I deside if API>=18 use 
MediaMuxer and if API<18 use other function. When targeting minSdkVersion="16" the function MediaMuxer  is now shown at all in eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test the version number like this

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
    // do high api
else {
    // do low api
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the target version of the Android device using below code

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {

System.out.println("Android Version of device is getter or equal to 16 ::Version::"
                        + android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
}else{

System.out.println("Android Version of device is getter or equal to 16 ::Version::"
                        + android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
}
```